# How to connect Jetty ( inGoogle App Engine) with JBoss AS 7.1?

Tags: jakarta-ee, gwt, jboss

I'd like to develop GWT on Jetty using Google App Engine (with Eclpise plugin) in developer mode. The GWT services/servlets need to use EJBs running on JBoss server. This is to be done on single computer. Can anyone point me in any direction how should I set it up? Alternativly having developer mode on JBoss would be ok for me as well. Unfortunatelly I gave up on the procedure  described in https://community.jboss.org/wiki/CreateGWTProjectsWithJBossToolsAndEclipseWTP as it didnt work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should run development mode in external server. [Here is description](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging#How_do_I_use_my_own_server_in_development_mode_instead_of_GWT%27s).

BTW. If you run on JBoss, take a look on [Errai](http://www.jboss.org/errai). As it is developped by JBoss, I somehow expect it should run nicely in JBoss; I used it in OSGi though.

Comment: I'm trying to use errai and osgi in combination. Could you please give some hints how to accomplish this?